# How to optimize render settings to speed up renders of black and white moire patterns in 4k?

Tags: rendering

I'm using Blender 2.79b on a laptop with i7-4700 4 core processor with 16GB of RAM with on-board graphics. I'm trying to optimize my render animations to render out in 4k. I don't have a GPU on my laptop. Can someone recommend some render settings that will speed up the render process? The image is black and white. I'm animating different moire test patterns.

Here's a YouTube link to the current animation done in a 480X480 resolution:
https://youtu.be/mVC4ieiLDUw

I know the render settings for 4k (see image below) the issue I have is speed and how can I increase it by turning certain render options off.

[image]

I've also included the blend file:

[image]

Since it's basically a Black and White animation I'm open to use any render engine, which ever render engine will speed things up.

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind my edit. I hope that will increase the chances of getting good answers faster. It would also be a good idea to mention the render engine you would like to use. Is it Cycles?

Comment: @MartinZ I'm ok with anything that helps.  And since it's basically a Black and White animation I'm open to use any render engine which ever render engine will speed things up.

Comment: What times are you expecting? I get around 2 sec (w/o Freestyle) for 4096x4096 image on 4 cores, would this be enough?

Comment: @SergeL I'm willing to try everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned off *Freestyle* rendering, raytracing, textures, FSAA (full sample AA), set all materials to shadeless. And finally I set rendering *Tile Size* to 1024px.

[image]